# To show only a part of the v-model data based on a condition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Here is my fiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/c7amyx6o/)

```
methods: {
  create() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.modules, null, 4))
  }
}
```

I have modules, their actions and its permissions.

```
<div v-for="(module, moduleIndex) in modules"><b>{{ module.moduleName }}</b>
    <div v-for="(action, actionIndex) in module.actions">{{ action.actionName }}
      <div v-for="(permission, permIndex) in action.permissions">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model='modules[moduleIndex].actions[actionIndex].permissions[permIndex].value'> {{ permission.permissionName }} - {{modules[moduleIndex].actions[actionIndex].permissions[permIndex].value}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

On choice of the checkboxes, the associated v-model gets updated. Is there a way I show only permissions for which the value in "true" in v-model or the displayed content.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Do you want to still show the modules and the actions or should those be hidden too if there is no permission with the value true?

Comment: @Matthias : https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/c7amyx6o/     Updated fiddle with expected output. I want the permissions with false value to be removed from the json. If permissions are false for an action, that action will be removed and if ALL permissions for ALL actions were to be  false, module itself will be removed from json

Comment: @Roy J : Please see https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/c7amyx6o/

Comment: So it's just the stringified JSON that you want to change? Use your `computed`; it's pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `updated_modules` computed just needs to filter out the false permissions, then filter out actions with no permissions and objects with no actions:

```
updated_modules: function() {
  var updated = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.modules));

  for (const obj of updated) {
    for (const action of obj.actions) {
      action.permissions = action.permissions.filter((p) => p.value);
    }
    obj.actions = obj.actions.filter((a) => a.permissions.length);
  }
  updated = updated.filter((o) => o.actions.length);

  return updated;
}
```

then remember to print it rather than the unmodified `modules`

```
<p> Result now </p>
<pre>{{ JSON.stringify(this.updated_modules,null,4)}}</pre>
```

and you have [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7amyx6o/6/).

Answer (score 0):

Since your view is already updating based on the values from the model with `v-if` I think what you want is that your `JSON.stringify(modules)` is updating accordingly.

You can do that by creating a computed property that deletes the permissions if their value is false.

An example could be this:

```
computed: {
    updated_modules: function() {
      var updated = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.modules));
      for(i = 0; i < updated.length; i++) {
        for(k = 0; k < updated[i].actions.length; k++) {
          for (j = 0; j < updated[i].actions[k].permissions.length; j++) {
            if(updated[i].actions[k].permissions[j].value == false) {
              updated[i].actions[k].permissions.splice(j, 1);
            } 
          }
        }
      }
      return updated;
    }
},
```

And then of course you wouldn't stringify the modules but updated_modules, see the updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/c7amyx6o/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/c7amyx6o/ Updated fiddle with expected output. I want the permissions with false value to be removed from the json. If ALL permissions are false for an action, that action will be removed and if ALL permissions for ALL actions were to be false, module itself will be removed from json

Comment: Hi, in your fiddle even when all checkboxes are unchecked "write permission" for all actions still appears in the JSON. Changing the arguments in the splice function to (j, 3) helps for this condition alone and for any other state of checkboxes, it does not seem to work, sorry. Could you please update it?